# How to convert an amount of different currency into words in java?

Tags: java, currency

I have an amount with different currencies, I want to convert an amount into words.suppose if i have a number 1000000,  i have to print it for "Rupees ten lakh only" for india, "Dollar one million only" for usa etc...

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks in advance,
Msn

Comment: You need to provide more details about your question with examples.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a stab in the dark and assume you're talking about String and int data types.
To append the value of the int type onto the String use the String's method `valueOf`, for example:

```
String formattednumber = "$" + String.valueOf(amount);
```

In the future please provide more information to exactly you want and what you have tried, also code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to print numbers as words then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720049/print-number-in-words) might be helpful.

same logic can be used to append currency name.
hope that helps.